# How to use relative path in compiler 'edg'?

Tags: c++, c, frontend, backend, edg

I use compiler 'edg' for front-end compilation

Let's assume I have got 2 files

```
a)  /build/src/a.c
b)  /build/include/a.h
```

I am able to compile 'a.c' by specifying `'-I /build/include'`
 but not using '-I../include'

How to use relative path using 'edg'?

Note:  I am compiling all the source files using 'xml' files and not from command-line

Answer (score 0):

Relative path, but relative to *what* ? I suspect that `-I../include` in fact works, and is relative to the current working directory of your compiler process. IOW, do a `cd /build/src` and `../include` will work.

I don't know what you mean by "using xml files"; but that doesn't take away the fact that the compiler process has a current working directory.

Comment: I had raised PMR with IBM for this and they are investing on this.  it appears Appscan ver 8.8 has problem with 'relative path'. Will post detailed answer once I get reply from them